# Creating new proxy using Zeppelin OS always use the same amount of gas

Tags: contract-development, proxy-contracts, openzeppelin-sdk

I'm building upgradeable infrastructure for the project and noticed that creation of proxy using Zeppelin OS always uses the same amount of gas.

How I understand, during the setting implementation to a proxy, it copies all storage of contract with the implementation. Logically, a different amount of gas should be used because of the different size of the data, but it always uses 592.000 of gas

Could anybody explain this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [articles](https://blog.zeppelinos.org/upgradeability-using-unstructured-storage/) [explainning](https://blog.zeppelinos.org/upgradeability-using-unstructured-storage/) how the contracts work.

The idea is you have a smart contract A used for storage, and a second contract B used for code.

Contract A contains a reference to contract B, and when someone invokes contract A it will make a `delegatecall` to contract B preserving the sender but storage modifications will be make to contract A storage.

To upgrade you deploy a new contract C, and updates the reference in contract A to point to the new contract. No migrations of data is necessary.

For all of this to work both contract B and C have to have a compatible data storage layout, ie the same storage variables and have to be defined in the same order.

I encourage you to read those articles for more details.